# Install Windows 10 language pack check box not available on a domain laptop

Tags: windows-10, language, windows-domain, input-languages, language-pack

Windows 10 add language pack dialog should look like this:

[image: Ok dialog]

But for me it looks like this:

[image: bad dialog]

https://www.windowscentral.com/how-properly-change-system-default-language-windows-10

I want to set the German language as system display language but it is not available from the settings.
Notebook is in a Windows domain on corporate network so I assume the language pack is not available on WSUS update server somehow.
How to workaround?

Comment: Are you an Administrator on the domain with the ability to add the package to your WSUS? If not ask your Administrator to install the language pack for you

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks, I am not. But on another virtual laptop which is in the same domain but different policy it shows OK.

Comment: As an unprivileged user you cannot solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, a colleague reminded me of this solution:

Use regedit in the folder:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate
```

and set value to 0 in following keys

```
DoNotConnectToWindowsUpdateInternetLocations
WUServer
```

This should bypass WSUS temporarily.